# Seeing results of compute and aggregate in BlueSky Statistics

Tags: output

In BlueSky Statistics when I compute a new column, why don't I see the result in output window?

Answer (score 0):

The new variables are appended to the far right-hand side of the data editor window. Only messages appear in the output window. This is just like SPSS if you're familiar with that.